# Как checkbox передать разные значения, при нажатии одно, когда не нажата пустое значение в переменную?

Tags: javascript

Все время передает одно первое значение нажата или нет.

```js
function onButtonClick() {
  var text = jsConsole.read('#first');
  var textFind = jsConsole.read('#second');
  var truee = jsConsole.read('#third');
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <div class="number">
    <label for="first">первое: </label>
    <input type="text" id="first" value="жили были жили дома жили Жили ЖИЛИ Жили" />
  </div> <br><br>
  <div class="number">
    <label for="second">второе: </label>
    <input type="text" id="second" value="жили" />
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="number">
    <label for="third">первое: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="third" name="chek" value='true' />
  </div> <br><br>
  <br><br>
  <div id="button">
    <a href="#" onclick="onButtonClick()">Кнопка</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="js-console" class="js-console">
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут вообще hidden#third? Не используйте элементы с одинаковыми id.

Comment: это я понял я и без него пробывал, и через классы все время одно значение независимо нажато или нет

Comment: типа type="nomber" не существует

Comment: Нажми кнопку `править` под вопросом, и правь `js`

Comment: с теми все нормально передает изменил и небыло проблем, если убрать value он передает все время on независимо

Comment: даже если radio 2 ставить все равно одно значение передает

Comment: вообще не понятно, что вам нужно. И у вас какой-то обгрызок кода `JS`. Сформулируйте задачу более корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это все писать на ванильном JS то можно считать значение checked и присвоить переменной значения используя условный оператор

```js
function onButtonClick() {
  var text = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var textFind = document.getElementById('second').value;
  var truee = document.getElementById('third').checked ? "true" : "";

  console.log("Text: ", text);
  console.log("textFind: ", textFind);
  console.log("truee :", truee);
  document.getElementById("fres").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("sres").innerHTML = textFind;
  document.getElementById("tres").innerHTML = truee;
}
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <div class="number">
    <label for="first">первое: </label>
    <input type="nomber" id="first" value="жили были жили дома жили Жили ЖИЛИ Жили" />
  </div> <br><br>
  <div class="number">
    <label for="second">второе: </label>
    <input type="nomber" id="second" value="жили" />
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="number">
    <label for="third">первое: </label>
    <input id="third" type="checkbox" name="chek" value='off' />

  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="button">
    <a href="#" onclick="onButtonClick()">Кнопка</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="result">
  <p id="fres"></p>
  <p id="sres"></p>
  <p id="tres"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, что нужно сделать

```js
const $console = document.querySelector('.js-console');
const $inputsCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('.number-checkbox');
const $inputsText = document.querySelectorAll('.number-text');
const setNewConsoleValue = () => {
let newConsoleText = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < $inputsCheckbox.length; i++) { 
    if ($inputsCheckbox[i].checked) {
      if (!newConsoleText) {
        newConsoleText = $inputsText[i].value;
      } else {
        newConsoleText = `${newConsoleText}, ${$inputsText[i].value}`;
      }
    }
  };

  $console.innerText = newConsoleText
};


$inputsCheckbox.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('change', () => {   
      setNewConsoleValue();
    });
});
```

```css
.number {
  width: 50%
}

#input {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <div class="number">
    <label for="first">первое: </label>
    <input type="text" class="number-text" id="first" value="жили были жили дома жили Жили ЖИЛИ Жили" />
  </div> <br><br>
  <div class="number">
    <label for="second">второе: </label>
    <input type="text" class="number-text" id="second" value="жили" />
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="number">
    <label for="checkbox-1">первое: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="number-checkbox" id="checkbox-1" />
  </div> <br><br>
   <div class="number">
    <label for="checkbox-2">второе: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="number-checkbox" id="checkbox-2" />
  </div> <br><br>
  <br><br>
  <div id="button">
    <a href="#" onclick="onButtonClick()">Кнопка</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="js-console" class="js-console"></div>
```